# Android: Client-Server communication with real device

Tags: android, client-server

I have an `application(client)` which communicates and receives messages from `Server(TCP connection)` with [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/). I'm able to communicate through emulator, but when I connect my tablet the communication fails. I don't understand why the device does't takes the same localhost address for communication.

Need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator is running on the same computer as your server? Then the emulator can use a localhost IP like 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.0. But your tablet is not your computer. First your tablet should be in the same network (LAN) as your computer and second the app on your tablet should use the LAN ip of the computer.

Comment: Ya this could be the reason. Thanks.